# How to add scss loader in webpacker angular rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, webpack, sass

I'm trying to study rails with angular but I stock with implementing scss-loader. I already search this in google. I already add what they are trying to do, but unfortunately nothing happen and I always got this error
`Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"`.

I add scss.d.ts

```
declare module "*.scss" {
    const content: string
    export default content
  }
```

and here is my environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const typescript =  require('./loaders/typescript')

environment.loaders.prepend('typescript', typescript)

environment.loaders.prepend('html', {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'html-loader',
      options: {
        minimize: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false,
        caseSensitive: true,
        customAttrSurround: [ [/#/, /(?:)/], [/\*/, /(?:)/], [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/] ],
        customAttrAssign: [ /\)?\]?=/ ]
      }
    }]
  })

environment.loaders.prepend('style', {
  test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
  use: [{
      loader: "to-string-loader"
  }, {
      loader: "css-loader"
  }, {
      loader: "resolve-url-loader"
  }, {
      loader: "sass-loader"
  }]
})

module.exports = environment
```

even add a `stylesheet_pack_tag`

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
<div>
<default-selector></default-selector>
</div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

I got error. Does my version of my sass-loader matters here?

```
{
  "name": "acbook_angular",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.10",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solve it by replacing my environment

```
environment.loaders.prepend('style', {
  test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
  use: [{
      loader: "to-string-loader"
  }, {
      loader: "css-loader"
  }, {
      loader: "resolve-url-loader"
  }, {
      loader: "sass-loader"
  }]
})
```

to this

```
environment.loaders.insert('sass', {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        "to-string-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
        "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
        "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
    ]
});
```

and thanks for this [link](https://github.com/amitai10/rails-angular-webpacker/issues/2)